# how do I use scp command in my batch file

Tags: batch-file, ssh, putty, scp

I am writing my first batch file and was not sure how to ssh to a server from the batch file. I would like to do scp commands to the server.

I googled it up but not a very clear answer, so I thought I would ask here.

Some say with putty, I have putty installed in my windows machine. Some, using Plink - no idea what that is. So, any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: does `C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe` work for you?

Comment: Your title says "ssh command", while you seem to talk about SCP transfers actually. These are two very different things. Please make your question clear. Also it would better suit [su].

Answer (score 4):

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp" C:\Users\mts7\mylife.tgz mts7@example.com:/home/mts7/`

1. Call the program (pscp)
2. Provide the file to copy (I provided you with an example of a local file)
3. Provide the user name, host name, and path to where the file will be copied

Switch steps 2 and 3 if you are going from your remote server to your local machine.

You may also specify the port and other options with pscp.

`pscp mylife.tgz mts7@example.com:/home/mts7/ -pw mypassword -P 22` might be a useful variation for you for providing a password and port.

Comment: Able to resolve the issue with this solution. Thanks @Martin

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw in an alternative, which maybe suffices for you. WinSCP has a scripting feature http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#example

Answer (score 0):

You can use pscp as below

```
pscp -pw mypassword -P 22 mylife.tgz mts7@example.com:/home/mts7/
```

as the below command throws an error "More than one remote source not supported"

```
pscp mylife.tgz mts7@example.com:/home/mts7/ -pw mypassword -P 22
```